# Combining side by side image files controls for a video in Beamer

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I am using the `animate` package in latex for a `beamer` presentation. I have two sets of figures that I want to turn into animations which I was able to do with the following commands

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,scale=.33]{10}{file-}{0}{100}
    \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \animategraphics[loop,controls,scale=.33]{10}{Efile-}{0}{100}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
    \end{frame}
```

So the figures are sided by side and they work correctly for animation. However, with this solution, I have to push the play button twice (once for each figure) to get them to play at the same time. However, I can't push both simultaneously and so one figure always plays, say, a second slower than the other. I want to be able to walk through the figures at the same time, and so I want to see if there is a way to still have my figures side by side, but for there to be only one set of controls that plays both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are including graphics side by side in pairs with a fast computer it is possible to do pairs of frames fast enough to not see too much difference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,animate} % for \animategraphics
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \centering
  \begin{animateinline}[
    poster=last, % this is the static cover image, usually set to last but can be set to none or frame number (0 = first)
    loop,
    controls,
    buttonbg=0.8:1:0.8
    ]{1} % frames per second 
   \multiframe{100}{I=0+1}{% 1st figure is total files per side, 0+1 = start with file-0.png
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{file-\I} \hspace{0.02cm}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Efile-\I}}
  \end{animateinline}   
 \end{frame}
\end{document}

From http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf
Page 4 Section 5 The user interface
\begin{animateinline}[<options>]{<frame rate>} 
%   ... typeset material ... 
%   \newframe[<frame rate>]
\multiframe{<number of frames>}{[<variables>]}
{ ... repeated (parameterized) material ... }
\end{animateinline}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, for some reason when I go to the slide it starts on the last image. Is there a way to make it start from the first image? Or should it be doing that?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I needed to ass poster = first instead of poster = last.